# Install CentOS 6 on HP ML 150 gen9 server with b140i raid controller

Tags: centos, raid, centos6, hp, hp-smart-array

I have HP ML 150 with Smart Array b140i controller.
I want to install CentOS 6.6, but the driver isn't built-in the ISO.

I have download the Driver and install in the USB(dd).

I need the command for check the USB, and where to put.

Comment: The HP driver disk documentation provides the commands needed to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The HP disk is [here](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_82b8addd965540b79e00640705), today.  It has a download link, and instructions on how to use it.

(You'll want to create the disk and then use a code on the boot screen so that the installer will ask for the disk at the right time.  That code may be like 'linux dd install')